# Unable to start process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/.../bin/java''

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.3

After upgrading Android Studio to 2.3, I keep seeing this error when building the project lately.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaLocalDebug'.
>
>   > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Cleaning and rebuilding did solve the problem. But it is very time consuming having to do this again and again. Any nicer work around?

Edit:

---

Compiling in terminal with `$ ./gradlew --stacktrace --info assembleDebug`:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaLocalDebug'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileRetrolambdaLocalDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)

        ... 
        ... 
        ... 

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.setEndStateInfo(DefaultExecHandle.java:197)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle.failed(DefaultExecHandle.java:327)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:86)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/yuchen/Documents/MountainView2/app"): error=7, Argument list too long
        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
        ... 5 more



BUILD FAILED
```

Compiling in terminal with `$ ./gradlew --stacktrace --debug assembleDebug`:

```
15:31:43.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 2 more
15:31:43.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/yuchen/Documents/MountainView2/app"): error=7, Argument list too long
15:31:43.654 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
15:31:43.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 4 more
15:31:43.655 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long
15:31:43.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 5 more
15:31:43.656 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:31:43.656 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
15:31:43.656 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Try building from the command line and include the recommended switches (`--stacktrace` and `--info` or `--debug`) and see if you get more details of what is going wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare, it took me a while to reproduce it. Here is stack trace (edited answer). It happens only once in a while, which is very annoying. Any clue?

Comment: "Argument list too long" is interesting. I take it that the log does not actually show the full command, with the arguments?

Comment: @CommonsWare I also include `--debug` (instead of `--info`), I have a bit more information: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" (in directory "/Users/yuchen/Documents/MountainView2/app"): error=7, Argument list too long`.  I guess maybe it is related to `jdk1.8.0_101.jdk` because the name is slightly longer than the previous version. But I am not 100% sure. The thing is that it doesn't happens consistently, only once in a while. So it may not be it.

Comment: @YuchenZhong I'm also seeing this, it also goes away with a clean and rebuild. For me, it only occurs with one of the Build Variants (usually the one I need, annoyingly), but works with the others.  Is that the same for you?

Comment: Hey @NelsonWright, I haven't paid much attention to which variant I used. But I don't think it is related to the variants. But yeah, clean & rebuild is the only solution that I found, which is very annoying! I guess what happened to you is that since you used mostly on variant **Foo**, you will notice it more. I would guess it happens on other variants for you too, just that you didn't notice because you've used them not as much?

Comment: @YuchenZhong You may be right about that, I just happened to notice that if it starts failing for one build variant, usually the others still work. It's strange that it complains about the argument list being too long for one build variant, and not the other!

Answer (score 3):

We found this happening due to the retrolamdba plugin, the error being in the values of the retrolambda arguments.

Upgrading the plugin fixed the problem. See release notes for version [3.2.5](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/releases)